# Print array in email message

Tags: php, arrays, loops, email, foreach

Trying to print a series of bookings in an email message.

The PHP is as follows:

```
<?php
  $checkbooking = $_POST['checkbooking']; // <--string of bookings separated by commas

  $bookings = explode(',', $checkbooking); // <-- removing the commas

  $to = "myemail@email.com";
  $subject = 'list of bookings';
  $headers = "From: do not reply" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  $message .= "Booking Report<br /><br>";
  $message .= '<html><body>';
  $message .= '<h3>NVR Bookings</h3><br />';
  $message .= foreach($bookings as $v){echo $v . "\n";}.'<br />';  // <-- my attempt to print the bookings
  $message .= '<br />';
  $message .= '<body></html>';

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

The foreach loop that you see in the message worked outside of the email function.  But as soon as I put it in the email, I get a 500 error, which is indeed isolated to the foreach in the email function.

How can I update the email function or the foreach loop to successfully display the bookings consecutively one underneath the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just concatenate PHP code into a string.  You need to execute the code and concatenate the string:

```
$message .= '<h3>NVR Bookings</h3><br />';
foreach($bookings as $v){ $message .= "$v\n<br />"; }
$message .= '<br />';
```

However, it would be easier to do one of the following, replace or join:

```
$bookings = str_replace(',', "\n<br />", $checkbooking);
//or
$bookings = implode("\n<br />", explode(',', $checkbooking));
```

Then:

```
$message .= '<h3>NVR Bookings</h3><br />';
$message .= $bookings;
$message .= '<br />';
```

Comment: Nice.  This is what worked for me.  Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

When you're concatenating strings, the expression on each side of the `.=` must evaluate to (or return) a string. `foreach` doesn't return a string. And furthermore, `echo` sends data to the standard output, not into a variable.

You need to loop and do the concatenation *within* the loop, on each individual item.

```
$message .= '<h3>NVR Bookings</h3><br />';
foreach($bookings as $v){ 
  $message .= $v."\n<br />"; 
}
$message .= '<br />';
```

---

But to be honest, I can see you are actually just replacing commas with newlines. So you could save yourself the exploding and looping and just do a string replace operation, which will do a straight swap of one character for the other in your string:

```
$message .= '<h3>NVR Bookings</h3><br />';
$message .= str_replace(",", "\n", $checkbooking);
$message .= '<br />';
```

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php